# Scaling webpage on desktop at different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which has a fixed layout.
It was built using standard size of 1280x800.

Since it doesn't need to be mobile compatible, and not accessed by the public, it was built using fixed size elements.

The problem is, I need it to scale automatically according to browser size.

I managed to do it with the viewport metatag, but that works only for mobile browser (which I do not need...)

e.g. How can the page display correctly, when opened in Chrome on a desktop with 1024x768 resolution, without the need to manually zoom out in the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the page to load zoomed out on smaller resolutions?

Comment: exactly, to fit in every resolution.
Doesn't have to fill in high resolution, but could be nice...

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. You could try adding some Javascript and upon loading fetching the window's width and then zooming in/out of the website accordingly.

Comment: Can you post your css code of a specific width you have used. Or are you using inline styling for the fixed layout?

Comment: So you built it with fixed sizes, not you don't want fixed sizes?

Comment: it is built fixed sized, I want it to stay fixed size, height and width, spacing, layout... nothing needs to be changed. just zooming in and out according to the target resolution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace every `px` with a `vw` based on the ratio of the width to the size at 1280x800.

So if you had a div with `width: 1280px` you would replace it with `width: 100vw`.

Set your `font-size` on the body in this way to get the text to scale, and use `em` or `rem` to size larger text.

If your font size was 16 at 1280x800, then you would want `font-size: 1.25vw`.

Comment: Tried using this idea, but if I have a button inside a div, the button is 50x50.
When I set width=?vw and height=?vh, the element proportions are wrong...

Comment: @Gabi You wouldn't want to use vh. Use vw for everything, including the heights.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries to achieve different styles at different screen widths (responsive). Here is an example of some different media queries.

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
}
```

Comment: To my understanding, you use responsiveness in order to change the layout of the page according to the resolution. In my case, the layout must not change at all.

Comment: You do not need to change the layout. Just resize everything to fit the smaller screen by adjusting widths and text size. There is no magic "zoom" option that will fix your website. Whether you use media queries or percent/vw widths to tackle the width changes on your site your are effectively making the site responsive.